# Solution of Ordinary Differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am a bit stuck with this one.

$y' = \displaystyle \frac{ax + by}{cx+dy}$ under the assumption that $ad \neq cb$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $y/x=v$

$y'=xv'+v$

Comment: How does one proceed from this point though? I have been trying this for some time but cannot do it.

Comment: Bring v to the other side and separate variables.

Comment: Yep, got it! Thanks!